# nodejs: complaining about an used model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I was following this tutorial https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd for building my first api.

Everything worked fine, and then I decided to change it to store locations and favorites, created a FavoritesModel.js and a LocationsModel.js.

My server.js now has

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Location = require('./api/models/LocationsModel'),
Favorite = require('./api/models/FavoritesModel'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db');
require("./api/models/LocationsModel");
require("./api/models/FavoritesModel"); 


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var routes = require('./api/routes/geolocationAPIRoutes');
routes(app);

app.listen(port);

console.log('geolocation RESTful API server started on: ' + port);

app.use(function(req, res) {
 res.status(404).send({url: req.originalUrl + ' not found'})
});
```

However, when i run `npm run start`, i get `MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Tasks".`

What am I doing wrong? There's no reference for Tasks anywhere anymore. Do I need to rebuild the API or something? I already did a `npm rebuild`.

Comment: I deleted that, there`s no more a Tasks schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Location = require('./api/models/LocationsModel'), // remove this
Favorite = require('./api/models/FavoritesModel'), // remove this
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db');
var Location = require("./api/models/LocationsModel");// change this
var Favorite = require("./api/models/FavoritesModel");// change this
```

You requires those models twice.
Remove those requires before connect. And sentence variables after connection.

Comment: Thanks, but now I am getting `Error: Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]`

Comment: @SuperMonteiro That's a different issue, not related with this one. But if you post your Route.post code here, I'll help you.

Comment: That`s the thing, I didnt write any Route.post() at all.

Comment: @SuperMonteiro What's inside './api/routes/geolocationAPIRoutes'?

Comment: ''use strict';
 module.exports = function(app) {
  var geolocation = require('../controllers/geolocationAPIController');

  app.route('/api/places')
    .get(geolocation.list_all_locations);
    //.post(geolocation.create_a_location);


  app.route('/api/places/:location')
    .get(geolocation.read_a_location)
    .post(geolocation.post_a_location)
    .put(geolocation.update_a_location);

  app.route('/api/places/favorites')
    .get(geolocation.list_all_favorites)
    .post(geolocation.post_a_favorite)
    .delete(geolocation.delete_a_favorite);
};' @zerocho

Comment: @SuperMonteiro Check out all the post method in that file. Check all of those callbacks are valid, whether there is any typo or not.

Comment: @SuperMonteiro Please accept this answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Comment: Done. I'm now having trouble trying to search a location by its locationName. Should I make a new thread?

Comment: @SuperMonteiro I think so